# import conflict two module react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two module `firebase` and `react-native-firebase`
I want import both ,how can do that?

```
import  firebase from 'firebase'

import {firebase as firebase2} from 'react-native-firebase';
```

when i want use it
`const messaging=firebase2.messaging()`

> error:Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating '_reactNativeFirebase.firebase.messaging')

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes ,const=firebase2.messaging()
error:Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeFirebase.firebase.messaging')

Answer (score 1):

> Import the Messaging package into your project:

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
```

> The package also provides access to the firebase instance:

```
import { firebase as firebase2 } from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
```